# Swipe left to delete, swipe right to rotate imageview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I am trying to use ItemTouchHelper.Simple callback to add Swipe To Delete to my recyclerview for LEFT swipes and I want to flip an imageview for RIGHT swipes WITHOUT moving the itemView position at all. Is there a way to use ItemTouchHelper to detect the right swipe and use that data to do a flip animation on my imageView within the itemView?

Comment: override `onSwiped` method and get direction like `ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT`

Comment: onSwiped isn't called unless you swipe the itemView off of the screen. I want to prevent the item view from moving to the right at all, but I still want to gesture info so I can flip and imageview, basically the same way Gmail flips their circular avatar, selecting the email thread.